# Restlet: Use same resource for "/customer" and "/customer/"

Tags: api, restlet

I would like to find a solution to use 2 routes for the same resource.

For instance, I am a resource CustomerResource and I would like to use this same resource for "/customer" and "/customer/" with a trailing slash added.

Do you have any suggestion about this ?

Regards,

EDIT: I override SpringBeanRouter to publish resource with and without trailing slash route:

```
public class MySpringBeanRouter extends SpringBeanRouter {

    @Override
    public TemplateRoute attach(String pathTemplate, Restlet target) {
        if(pathTemplate != null && pathTemplate.endsWith("/"))
            super.attach(pathTemplate.substring(0, pathTemplate.length() - 1), target);

        return super.attach(pathTemplate, target);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to attach the same resource class under two different routes:

router.attach("/customer", CustomerServerResource.class);

router.attach("/customer/", CustomerServerResource.class);

Comment: OK thanks, since I would like this to be automatic I override SpringBeanRouter as you can see in first post